# Chrome extension "version error"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I was testing out chrome extensions and learning how to use them but I get the same error when I upload my code... It says

Failed to load extension from: ~\Desktop\chromeExtension
The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes). See developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html for details.

I have a manifest.json file and icon.png file

manifest.json:

```
{
     "name": "Hello World!",
     "version": 2,
     "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
     "browser_action": {
         "default_icon": "icon.png"
     }
}
```

icon.png:
[image]

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? I uploaded my chrome extension at the chrome://extension page, hit the developer mode button, pressed load unpacked extension, and then opened a file called chromeExtension containing the manifest.json and icon.png. Any ideas on how to fix the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `manifest_version`, not just the `version`. The `version` key is simply the version of your extension:

```
{
    "name": "Hello World!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked and now I have my extension! Much gratitude to you.

Comment: Note also that `manifest_version` is an int, but `version` is a string.